# Filtering on Two Different Combo Boxes

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form that opens with a query as its record source based on some predefined criteria. The form also has subforms that loads based on the links created and in fact there are to link criterias: Hours and Year. 
Here is what I am trying to achieve: I have two combo boxes. I select a value in the first combo box and then after I select a value in the second combo box, the record source much filter on after update event of this combo box based on the two values selected. I want the form to filter by using values in both the hour and the year combo boxes. The event is triggered when the values in second combo box is selected. 
Is is possible to code it this way?
DoCmd.ApplyFilter , "[Hours]=cboHour.value" AND "[Year]=cboYear.Value".

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
Me.Filter = "[Hours] = " & Me!cboHour.Value & " And [Year] = " & Me!cboYear.Value & ""
Me.FilterOn = True
```